# Adding alt text to multiple images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I'm trying to add alt text to multiples of the same image with Javascript.  I can't directly access the html, and they do not have an id or class for me to select.  I'm currently selecting the image by role.  Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
<button class="collapsible collapsed az-toggle" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#additional-info-35434414" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="additional-info-35434414">
<span class="d-inline-flex rotate-n180 me-2 align-middle az-collapsible">
<img src="/web/assets/media/icons/duotune/arrows/arr072.svg" role="presentation">
</span>
```

The Javascript I'm using is:

```
<script>

var imageElement = document.querySelector("[role=presentation]");

if (imageElement) {

imageElement.alt = 'Additional info arrow';

}

</script>
```

The problem is this only adds alt text to the first image, and then stops.  There are 43 other identical images that need this alt text.  Is there a way to have this repeat the needed number of times?  I've tried using document.querySelectorAll("[role=presentation]"), but that doesn't work.

Comment: "*I've tried using document.querySelectorAll("[role=presentation]"), but that doesn't work.*"  did it not work because you didn't loop through the result? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845)

Answer (score 3):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, you need to iterate over each element to set the alt text:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("[role=presentation]");
    
images.forEach(function(imageElement) {
   imageElement.alt = 'Additional info arrow';
});
```

Comment: Ok, this helps.  Now something weird is happening, though.  There are 4 hidden images with role=presentation, and 37 images that are displayed with role=presentation.  For some reason, this is only targeting the ones that are not displayed, and not changing the displayed images, even though they also have role= presentation.  Any ideas why that might happen?  Is there any way to target those images by src instead of role?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Note that "additional info arrow" is probably not a very good alt text. If the image has a function when clicked, the alt text should tell what it does, not what it looks like.